# C++ template class's template specialization

Tags: c++

I am trying to specialize this template method 'he' but couldn't compile. How to do it right?

```
    #pragma once
            template<typename A, typename B>
            class template_test
            {
            public:
                template_test();
                ~template_test();

              template<typename C>
              void he(C gg);

            };



            template<typename A, typename B>
            template<typename C>
            void template_test<A, B>::he( C gg )
            {

            }

            template<typename A, typename B>
            template<>
            void template_test<A, B>::he( int gg )
            {

            }
```

error C1506: unrecoverable block scoping error
unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Comment: Note: when posting "why doesn't my code compile??" questions, it is customary to post the compiler error output **verbtim**, and you will likely *always* be asked for it (like right now). And that isn't a method overload, that is a specialization. (unless I'm completely misunderstanding your intent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specialize the class also. You cannot just specialize only the member:

```
template<>
template<>
void template_test<int, int>::he<int>( int gg )
{

}
```

However, instead, I would just add an overload:

```
 void he(int gg){}
```

Comment: +1 likewise agreed on adding the overload rather than trying to specialize this.